# Is a Windows 10 localized entirely to the filesystem of the drive it's installed on?

Tags: linux, windows, backup, filesystems

With the recent news Windows wise I have realized I am tired of the Windows ecosystem and want to move to something different. Linux is my first choice.

I'm a little hesitant, being a Windows user for my entire life. I want to test the waters of distros first before jumping in.

Thus poses my question. Could I clone my entire Windows C: to a backup drive and in the event something goes wrong with my Linux installation/experience, could I just format the Linux C: and paste the Windows C: backup back and have Windows fully functioning again? Would this have any detriments on drivers/Windows installation key?

As a side question, if I do fully switch to Linux how would the filesystem type (NTFS) of my Windows media affect the transition?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to test Linux is to install *on Windows* the
[Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)
with the Linux distribution of your choice.
WSL Linux is a real Linux distribution, although it requires also
adding an X server for the graphical interface.
You will find many tutorials for doing that on the internet.

Alternatively, you could *on Windows* create a Linux virtual machine
for testing. This would be a full Linux environment
(while I would describe WSL as 99% distribution).

The next step might be to install Linux and Windows in dual-boot.
This will involve resizing down the Windows partition,
to make space for the Linux partition.

You can always remove totally either Windows or Linux from dual-boot,
once you decide to stay with only one of them.

If you have more than one disk, just remember that NTFS is not a
natural file-system format on Linux, so there might be problems
when using NTFS on Linux.